# Push screen bottom on top of keyboard in flutter when TextField or TextFormField is focused

Tags: flutter

I want to achieve a layout where only the main button widget will always remain at the bottom of the scaffold. Other widgets will be placed in a `SingleChildScrollView` -> `Column`.

But when the `TextField` or `TextFormField` is focused, the keyboard should push the full screen till the bottom of the layout, so that the button is visible.

Using SingleChildScrollView only keeps the `TextField` or `TextFormField` above the keyboard, not the button too.

My code:

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Container(
            height: screenHeight(context) - kToolbarHeight - 24,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                PlaceHolder(),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                Text('Select Time'),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                PlaceHolder(),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                PlaceHolder(),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                // InputField is a TextFormField
                InputField(
                  controller: _dataController,
                  labelText: 'Enter Data',
                  fieldFocusNode: _dataFocusNode,
                  textInputType: TextInputType.text,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                CheckboxListTile(),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                PrimaryButton(
                  buttonText: 'Save',
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Here's two screen layout. You can ignore all the other widgets except `TextFormField` and the `Main Button`.

**Screen One : Without keyboard (`TextField` or `TextFormField` is not focused)**

[image: Screen One : Without keyboard (TextField or TextFormField is not focused)]

**Screen Two : With keyboard (`TextField` or `TextFormField` is focused)**

[image: Screen Two : With keyboard (TextField or TextFormField is focused)]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Follow this steps:

**1.** Remove the `Container` with fixed height.

**2.** Add a `Padding` widget to the bottom of the page and set its `bottom` padding to `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom`.

**3.** Add `reverse: true` to the `SingleChildScrollView`.

**4.** Add `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` to the `Scaffold`.

**5.** Add `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` to the `Scaffold`.

**Full code**: (changes are marked with comments)

```
return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // this is new
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false, // this is new
      body: SingleChildScrollView( 
        reverse: true, // this is new 
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column( // the container is removed
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            PlaceHolder(),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Text('Select Time'),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            PlaceHolder(),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            PlaceHolder(),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            // InputField is a TextFormField
            InputField(
              controller: _dataController,
              labelText: 'Enter Data',
              fieldFocusNode: _dataFocusNode,
              textInputType: TextInputType.text,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            CheckboxListTile(),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            PrimaryButton(
              buttonText: 'Save',
              onPressed: null, // changed this since it had a syntax error
            ),
            Padding( // this is new
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom)
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: You are a fking genius. +1.

Its working even today.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your screen with  `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: That only keeps the TextField above the keyboard, not the button too.

Comment: If you remove the height from the Container will it work @AbdullahAlNahid?

Comment: One of the placeholder widget is a Gridview which requires a height. Container height helps for that. Without container height, Gridview within Column crashes.

Comment: Wrap the GridView with Expanded and remove the height.